# filter an array of object using an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an array of objects out by an array of strings

```js
let allUsers = [
{
  "avatar":null,
  "deleted":false,
  "_id":"5f1f5df967b3240004f50a36",
  "email":"emailroom3@test.com",
  "password":"$2a$10$5eKv6OVouPnPH.3g9STEYO990V.L14kpD2ImZ3AtZtHaRjCg4oj/6",
  "fcm":"fcm3",
  "createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:33.683Z",
  "updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:33.683Z",
  "__v":0
},
{
  "avatar":null,
  "deleted":false,
  "_id":"5f1f5e0067b3240004f50a37",
  "email":"emailroom2@test.com",
  "password":"$2a$10$czA2dASdEo1Dw0oAxw.y1eJwg4lrZW12tLE6sUeG5k.PThuineTIm",
  "fcm":"fcm2",
  "createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:40.702Z",
  "updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:40.702Z","__v":0
},
{
  "avatar":null,
  "deleted":false,
  "_id":"5f1f5d9167b3240004f50a33",
  "email":"emailroom1@test.com",
  "password":"$2a$10$0O2aDCCSibWlNznIWfHTxuY8vNq4Sge/YDRuntKJl9UKnSI.9TEfC",
  "fcm":"fcm1",
  "createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z",
  "updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z",
  "__v":0
}]

let connectedUsers = ['5f1f5df967b3240004f50a36','5f1f5e0067b3240004f50a37']
```

the output should be the third user who isn't in the second array :

```js
myArrayFiltered = [
  {
    "avatar":null,
    "deleted":false,
    "_id":"5f1f5d9167b3240004f50a33",
    "email":"emailroom1@test.com",
    "password":"$2a$10$0O2aDCCSibWlNznIWfHTxuY8vNq4Sge/YDRuntKJl9UKnSI.9TEfC",
    "fcm":"fcm1",
    "createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z",
    "updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z",
    "__v":0
  }
]
```

I tried

```
 let myArrayFiltered = allUsers.filter((user) => {
    return connectedUsers.some((el) => {
      return user._id !== el;
    });
  });
```

but it returns all 3 users

**Edit**:
all the answers return the 2 users in the second array , but I want is the user who is not , the user with the id '5f1f5d9167b3240004f50a33'

Comment: Have you tried using `connectedUsers.includes(user._id)` inside the filter callback?

Comment: If an arrow function has only 1 argument, you can get rid of the parenthesis. This: `(user) => {`. Can be this: `user => {`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate through the second array. You just have to check if the `user._id` is in the `connectedUsers` array. Like this:

```js
let allUsers = [{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5df967b3240004f50a36","email":"emailroom3@test.com","password":"$2a$10$5eKv6OVouPnPH.3g9STEYO990V.L14kpD2ImZ3AtZtHaRjCg4oj/6","fcm":"fcm3","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:33.683Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:33.683Z","__v":0},{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5e0067b3240004f50a37","email":"emailroom2@test.com","password":"$2a$10$czA2dASdEo1Dw0oAxw.y1eJwg4lrZW12tLE6sUeG5k.PThuineTIm","fcm":"fcm2","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:40.702Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:40.702Z","__v":0},{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5d9167b3240004f50a33","email":"emailroom1@test.com","password":"$2a$10$0O2aDCCSibWlNznIWfHTxuY8vNq4Sge/YDRuntKJl9UKnSI.9TEfC","fcm":"fcm1","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z","__v":0}];
let connectedUsers = ['5f1f5df967b3240004f50a36','5f1f5e0067b3240004f50a37'];
let myArrayFiltered = allUsers.filter(user => {
  return connectedUsers.includes(user._id);
});
console.log(myArrayFiltered);
  
// myArrayFiltered = [{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5d9167b3240004f50a33","email":"emailroom1@test.com","password":"$2a$10$0O2aDCCSibWlNznIWfHTxuY8vNq4Sge/YDRuntKJl9UKnSI.9TEfC","fcm":"fcm1","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z","__v":0}]
```

Comment: Also I think you can really just say `allUsers.filter(users => connectedUsers.includes(user._id));` excluding the return statement to make the code more elegant/simple.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was going to suggest. One small thing to note though: `includes()` does not seem to have IE support and that bit me once in production (which sucks because I think it reads very elegantly). If you need wider browser support, you can do the same thing with  `indexOf()`. It returns `-1` for items that does not exist in the array, so this would do the same thing with Dillan's more readable function: `allUsers.filter( u => connectedUsers.indexOf(u._id) >= 0)` (edit: although, judging from the example data, this is more likely to be server side code I guess)

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. Thank you for pointing that out. Personally I use `!== -1` when I use indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you are checking whether some elements don't equal the user id, but you probably mean to check whether some elements match it:

```
let myArrayFiltered = allUsers.filter((user) => {
  return connectedUsers.some((el) => {
    return user._id === el;
  });
});
```

This correctly returns only 2 users.

Comment: but I'm trying to get the user who isn't in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf method to check item in array or not as

```
let myArrayFiltered = allUsers.filter((user) => {
        return connectedUsers.indexOf(user._id) > -1;
      });
```

```js
let allUsers = 
[{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5df967b3240004f50a36","email":"emailroom3@test.com","password":"$2a$10$5eKv6OVouPnPH.3g9STEYO990V.L14kpD2ImZ3AtZtHaRjCg4oj/6","fcm":"fcm3","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:33.683Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:33.683Z","__v":0},{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5e0067b3240004f50a37","email":"emailroom2@test.com","password":"$2a$10$czA2dASdEo1Dw0oAxw.y1eJwg4lrZW12tLE6sUeG5k.PThuineTIm","fcm":"fcm2","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:40.702Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:06:40.702Z","__v":0},{"avatar":null,"deleted":false,"_id":"5f1f5d9167b3240004f50a33","email":"emailroom1@test.com","password":"$2a$10$0O2aDCCSibWlNznIWfHTxuY8vNq4Sge/YDRuntKJl9UKnSI.9TEfC","fcm":"fcm1","createdAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z","updatedAt":"2020-07-27T23:04:49.285Z","__v":0}]
 let connectedUsers = ['5f1f5df967b3240004f50a36','5f1f5e0067b3240004f50a37']
 
  let myArrayFiltered = allUsers.filter((user) => {
    return connectedUsers.indexOf(user._id) > -1;
  });
  
  console.log(myArrayFiltered)
```